# How to add browser server to upload images in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, json, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor in my web, I have intergated CKeditor and want to upload my image from pc to server
I refer this link:

```
http://devture.com/projects/ckeditor-imagebrowser/demo/
```

this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- <h2><label for="editor1">Developer Site Editor</label></h2> -->
    <textarea name="ir1" id="ir1" rows="1" cols="10" style="width:580px; height:600px; min-width:400px; min-height:50px; display:none;"> </textarea>
</div>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'ir1', {
    // Define the toolbar: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar
    // The standard preset from CDN which we used as a base provides more features than we need.
    // Also by default it comes with a 2-line toolbar. Here we put all buttons in a single row.
    toolbar: [
    { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'CodeSnippet', 'Image', 'Mathjax', 'EmbedSemantic', 'Table' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Format', 'Styles' ] }
],          

...
</script>
```

When I run and icon image display but it is not include 'browsers server' button

How to add 'Browsers Server' button in CKEditor ? Thank so much !!

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [link](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload) as well as other links from that section.

Basically you should set at minimum these two settings: [filebrowserBrowseUrl](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserBrowseUrl)  and [filebrowserUploadUrl](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserUploadUrl) advanced file manager like e.g. [CKFinder](https://cksource.com/ckfinder) or to some custom code which will handle uploads and file browsing for you.

Please also note that [File Browser](https://ckeditor.com/addon/filebrowser) plugin is required (it is available by default in standard and full packages).